# Bind a list to silverlight datagrid/datafrom columns

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, dataform

There must be something I am missing, I want to do a very simple thing, for example, I have a class like the following:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public List<string> phoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind it to a dataform by something like this:

```
 public Person person { get; set; }
 private void GetPerson()
 {
 List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        lst.Add("123445");
        lst.Add("2345345");
        lst.Add("4576345");
        lst.Add("456784");
        lst.Add("789067");

        person = new Person()
        {
            ID = 1,
            FirstName = "Kevin",
            LastName = "Dockx",
            DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1981, 5, 5),
            phoneNumbers= lst

        };
 }
```

and then

```
  GetPerson();
  dataForm1.CurrentItem = person;
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Those statements where you create a new list, add items to the list and create a new person need to be in a method. You cannot have those statements outside a method (at the same level as the Person property definition).

As a side note -- certainly you must be getting compiler errors when you try to build this code. I highly recommend getting in the habit of trying to understand and make sense out of specific compiler errors -- because they already tell you *what you're doing wrong* :)

Comment: Hi Eren, Thanks for the tip, actually the part you pointed out is inside a method body, I have no problem with that. I added the code to give you an idea what I am doing. I should've mentioned the method... It is changed now. I am having trouble binding the list to a dataform/ datagrid column.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the problem? What do you mean by "having trouble"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I do not want to specify the name of my List property in the binding syntax. e.g. If I had a combobox, and wanted it to bind to the phoneNumbers property, I would do something like comboBox1.ItemsSource = person.phoneNumbers; But in my case I wont know the name of the list property beforehand. that is why I am not able to define datafields like the exaples show. dataForm1.CurrentItem = person; works as long as person doesnot have a list property. the dataform shows System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] for phoneNumbers. I want the dataform to generate a combobox for phoneNumbers.